# Run out of memory when saving list with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a fairly large list of lists representing the tokens in the Sogou text classification data set. I can process the entire training set of 450 000 with 12 gigs of ram left over, but when I call numpy.save() on the list of lists the memory usage seems to double and I run out of memory.

Why is this? Does the numpy.save convert the list before saving but retain the list thus using more memory?

Is there an alternative way to save this list of lists i.e pickling? I believe numpy save uses the pickle protocol judging from the allow pickle argument: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

```
print "Collecting Raw Documents, tokenize, and remove stop words"
df = pd.read_pickle(path + dataSetName + "Train")
frequency = defaultdict(int)

gen_docs = []
totalArts = len(df)
for artNum in range(totalArts):
    if artNum % 2500 == 0:
        print "Gen Docs Creation on " + str(artNum) + " of " + str(totalArts)
    bodyText = df.loc[artNum,"fullContent"]
    bodyText = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', str(bodyText))
    bodyText = re.sub(pun, " ", str(bodyText))
    tmpDoc = []
    for w in word_tokenize(bodyText):
        w = w.lower().decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
        #if w not in STOPWORDS and len(w) > 1:
        if len(w) > 1:
            #w = wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w)
            w = re.sub(num, "number", w)
            tmpDoc.append(w)
            frequency[w] += 1
    gen_docs.append(tmpDoc)
print len(gen_docs)

del df
print "Saving unfiltered gen"
dataSetName = path + dataSetName
np.save("%s_lemmaWords_noStop_subbedNums.npy" % dataSetName, gen_docs)
```

Comment: What are these "tokens"? Numeric data? Or more complex objects?

Comment: Strings, each is a word

Comment: Why are you using numpy to save a list of lists? That doesn't make any sense, I wouldn't be surprised if it tries to create an array out of it first.

Comment: You should use `pickle` or JSON or even make it a CSV

Comment: I did try allow_pickle=False: raise ValueError("Object arrays cannot be saved when "
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be saved when allow_pickle=False

Comment: Juanpa I didn't try with pickle as I read it uses a large amount of RAM to pickle objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871152/why-pickle-eat-memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.save` first tries to convert the input into an array.  After all it is designed to save numpy arrays.

If the resulting array is multidimensional with numeric or string values (dtype) it saves some basic dimension information, plus a memory copy of the arrays data buffer.

But if the array contains other objects (e.g. dtype object), then it pickles those objects, and saves the resulting string(s).

I would try

```
arr = np.array(gen_docs)
```

Does that produce a memory error?

If not, what is its `shape` and `dtype`?

If the `tmpDoc` (sublists) vary in length the `arr` will be a 1d array with object dtype - those objects being the `tmpDoc` lists.

Only if all the `tmpDoc` have the same length will it produce a 2d array.  Even then the dtype will depend on the elements, whether numbers, strings, or other objects.

I might add that an array is pickled with the `save` protocol.

Comment: I already tried: gen_docs = np.array(gen_docs) and then saving it, same issue. The tmpDoc sublists do vary in length. I'll update this with a shape and dtype after the code runs again.

Comment: If you can't turn the whole list into an array, it might still be useful to convert part of it with: `np.rray(gen_docs[:100])`.  The same questions about shape and dtype apply.

Comment: Running it with 2500 documents just to check the shape and dtype this is what I got: (2500,) object

Comment: So it's a 1d array of those `tmpDoc` lists.  There's no real benefit to trying to save it with `numpy`.

Comment: @hpaulj, I tried everything to save numpy array (1D float): mgzip, pickle, gz2, plain file, numpy.save*, blosc+pickle. In any case without succes, python process has been killed because of lack of memory (even I have 276GB swapp on SSD partition). I couldn't manage to save slices, thought.