# np.save consume too much memeory for big arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, save, pickle

I have numpy arrays around 5 gig and working on python 3.x ubuntu 18.

When I try to numpy.save its consume nearly 2,5X memory. Is there any way to dump this data to disk without consume so much memory ?

Best

Comment: Possibly [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857782/run-out-of-memory-when-saving-list-with-numpy).

Comment: If you're saving big numeric data to disk, you might want to consider using HDF5, which is designed for that. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619199/best-way-to-preserve-numpy-arrays-on-disk?rq=1).